# Simple pulldown option in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xhtml

How do I make a pull down menu (or what is it called?)

On facebook you can click on...
"friends request" the friends request block will be displayed.
"notification" the notification block will be displayed.

On stackoverflow, you click on that arrow next to your "name" it displays your activity.

What is that called and how do you do it? example in http://jsfiddle.net/?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many plugins available out there. Here's [a list](http://speckyboy.com/2011/07/04/15-fresh-jquery-menu-plugins-and-tutorials/) to pick from if you don't want to roll your own.

Answer (score 2):

You register a `click` [event handler](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Handling_events_with_JavaScript), and then add additional elements (representing the new content) to [the DOM](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Creating_and_modifying_HTML).